# Parsing input file

Tags: java, parsing, io

**This is my input file:**

```
0  I  4325  <4214, 6>  <4718, 9>  <1203, 11> 
18  L  4214  12  <4325, 6>  <4718, 5>  <1483, 9>
35  F  4109
```

I am trying to write a method that will read in the first column, second column `(either I, L or F)` and store all the pairs in each row `e.g., (4214, 6), (4718, 9)`. What I've done is used the delimiter from the scanner class  to get rid of `'<', ',' and '>'`, and it does but when I try calling `temp.next()`, I keep on getting an error. My code is below (sometime the error goes away when I use `skip(" ")`:

```
public void parseFile(Scanner input) {

        int prevSeqNo = -1;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            if (!line.startsWith("#") && !line.isEmpty()) { // ignore comments
                                                            // and blank lines
                Scanner temp = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("<|,| |>"); // ignore all '<', ',' and '>'

//              while(temp.hasNext())
//                  System.out.print(" " + temp.next() );
//              System.out.println();

                int timeStamp = temp.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Timestamp: " + timeStamp);
                temp.skip(" ");
                String event = temp.next();
                System.out.println("Event: " + event);

                if (event.equals("I")) {
                    temp.skip(" ");
                    startNode = temp.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("starting node: " + startNode);

//                  while (temp.hasNext()) {
                        temp.skip("  ");
                        int node = temp.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(node);
                        temp.skip("");

                        int weight = temp.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(weight);
//                      System.out.println("<" + node + ", " + weight + ">");
//                  }
                } else if (event.equals("L")) {
                    int currSeqNo = temp.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Sequence number: " + currSeqNo); // discard if LSP has smaller or equal sequence number to max seen so far
                    if (currSeqNo >= prevSeqNo) {

                        prevSeqNo = currSeqNo; // update the previous sequence
                                                // number
                    } else { // else if event == "F"

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
```

After removing symbols:

```
 0  I  4325   4214  6    4718  9    1203  11 
 18  L  4214  12   4325  6    4718  5    1483  9
 29  L  4109  78   4718  3    1483  2  
 35  F  4109
```

Here is the error message:

```
Timestamp: 0
Event: I
starting node: 4325
4214
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at LinkedStateRouting.parseFile(LinkedStateRouting.java:41)
    at LinkedStateRouting.main(LinkedStateRouting.java:88)
```

Comment: what is the error? add the full stacktrace

Comment: maybe `System.out.println(node);
                        temp.skip(" ");`

Comment: do you know why I have to use temp.skip(" ") in the first place? I thought the scanner automatically skips whitespace.

Comment: sorry no idea.  personally I would have just read each line, replace'd the junk and the split into a String array and then processed from there

Comment: Ok I got it to work (I'm not sure why it works so an explanation would be much appreciated!). So instead of doing Scanner(line).useDelimiter("<|,| |>"), I modified the string using String modified = line.replaceAll("[<,>]", "") and then passed it to the scanner (Scanner temp = new Scanner(modified)). Now I can cal nextInt without having to worry about the whitespace.

Comment: Because when you set a custom delimiter `useDelimiter("<|,| |>"); ` - you are overriding the default delimiter that skips whitespaces. The default delimiter to skip whitespaces is `\p{javaWhitespace}+`. So you can instead use this delimiter `"\\p{javaWhitespace}+|<|,| |>"`. A word of caution though, when you have two consecutive delimiters in input - e.g. `  <` - i.e. white space followed by `<`, Scanner will return an empty token on `next()` or may throw exception on `nextInt()`, so you need to cater for empty tokens being returned. Fix that and you should be ok

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, Pat. It all makes sense now!